# To make matters worse -- meaning

Tags: meaning

In the sentence I've found in [the dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-russian/matter_1) while exploring the meaning of the word matter:

> ***To make matters worse***, our car broke down.

Couldn't you explain the meaning of it. I'm particular interested in the ***To make matters worse*** phrase. I presume it means that we were not being good and the things become even worse when our car broke down.

Comment: *Matters* refers to the situation at hand.  One could also say "to make things worse..."

Answer (score 2):

Correct. Things were already not going well, and then something bad *with a likely unrelated cause* happened, compounding into a worse situation.